# optimize mysql query across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, explain

I am having some issues optimizing the following query that joins multiple tables.

```
SELECT count(*) as count, `snapshot_id`, `snapshot_guid`, `image`, `subject`, `name`, `brands`.`facebook`, `brands`.`brand_id`, `brand_guid`, `date_sent`
FROM (`snapshots`)
INNER JOIN `brands` ON `snapshots`.`brand_id` = `brands`.`brand_id`
WHERE `snapshots`.`status` =  1
AND `brands`.`status` =  1
AND `brands`.`archive` =  0
GROUP BY `snapshots`.`brand_id`, `snapshots`.`subject`
ORDER BY `date_sent` desc
LIMIT 20
```

Execution Time: 4.9 seconds

Using EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type  table       type   possible_keys                           key                   key_len    ref                                   rows Extra
1     SIMPLE         brands      ALL    PRIMARY,brand_id,status,brand_status    NULL                    NULL       NULL                                338  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1     SIMPLE         snapshots   ref    brand_id,status,snapshot_brand_status   snapshot_brand_status   5          mockd_catalog.brands.brand_id,const 166
```

Describe Tables for Brands and Snapshots:

**Describe brands**

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
brand_id    int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
brand_guid  char(12)    NO  MUL NULL    
friendly    varchar(128)    YES     NULL    
name    varchar(128)    NO      NULL    
url varchar(2048)   YES     NULL    
logo    text    YES     NULL    
cover   text    YES     NULL    
facebook    varchar(2048)   YES     NULL    
address_1   varchar(128)    YES     NULL    
address_2   varchar(128)    YES     NULL    
city    varchar(50) YES     NULL    
state   varchar(50) YES     NULL    
postal  varchar(20) YES     NULL    
country_code    varchar(128)    YES     NULL    
date_created    datetime    YES     NULL    
date_modified   datetime    YES     NULL    
hp_snapshot tinyint(1)  NO      0   
status  tinyint(1)  YES MUL 0   
archive tinyint(1)  NO      0
```

**Describe snapshots**

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
snapshot_id int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
snapshot_guid   char(36)    YES MUL NULL    
brand_id    int(11) NO  MUL 0   
email   varchar(256)    NO  MUL NULL    
seed_email  varchar(256)    NO      NULL    
date_sent   datetime    NO  MUL NULL    
date_created    datetime    NO      NULL    
date_modified   datetime    YES     NULL    
content_type    varchar(10) YES     NULL    
subject varchar(256)    NO      NULL    
source  longtext    YES     NULL    
html    longtext    NO      NULL    
html_error  text    YES     NULL    
thumbnail   text    YES     NULL    
image   text    YES     NULL    
status  tinyint(1)  NO  MUL 0   
archive tinyint(1)  NO      0   
tags    text    YES     NULL
```

I've tried everything that I can think of, and can't seem to further optimize this query. Any help is appreciated.

Rick

edit 3/22/2015 @ 10:27am ET:

```
    CREATE TABLE `snapshots` (
  `snapshot_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `snapshot_guid` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `seed_email` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `date_sent` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `content_type` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `source` longtext,
  `html` longtext NOT NULL,
  `html_error` text,
  `thumbnail` text,
  `image` text,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '-1= error, 0 = new, 1 = approved, 2 = review ',
  `archive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tags` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`snapshot_id`),
  KEY `snapshot_id` (`snapshot_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `brand_id` (`brand_id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`(255)),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `snapshot_guid` (`snapshot_guid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `subject` (`subject`(255)),
  KEY `archive` (`archive`),
  KEY `archive_status` (`archive`,`status`),
  KEY `date_sent` (`date_sent`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `recent_snapshots` (`snapshot_id`,`snapshot_guid`,`archive`,`status`,`brand_id`,`date_sent`,`subject`(255)) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=95002 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Brands Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `brands` (
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand_guid` char(12) NOT NULL,
  `friendly` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `logo` text,
  `cover` text,
  `facebook` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_1` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_2` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postal` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `hp_snapshot` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `archive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`brand_id`),
  KEY `brand_guid` (`brand_guid`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `brand_id` (`brand_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `archive_status` (`archive`,`status`),
  KEY `archive` (`archive`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=423 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The select statement:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    `snapshot_id`,
    `snapshot_guid`,
    `image`,
    `subject`,
    `name`,
    `brands`.`facebook`,
    `brands`.`brand_id`,
    `brand_guid`,
    `date_sent`
FROM
    (`snapshots`)
        INNER JOIN
    `brands` ON `snapshots`.`brand_id` = `brands`.`brand_id`
WHERE
    `snapshots`.`archive` = 0
        AND `snapshots`.`status` = 1
        AND `brands`.`archive` = 0
        AND `brands`.`status` = 1
GROUP BY `snapshots`.`brand_id` , `snapshots`.`subject`
ORDER BY `date_sent` DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Explain:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  snapshots   ref brand_id,status,archive,archive_status  status  1   const   48304   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  brands  eq_ref  PRIMARY,brand_id,status,archive_status,archive  PRIMARY 4   mockd_catalog.snapshots.brand_id    1   Using where
```

Comment: would you please post the SQL DDL of the above two tables instead of "DESC table_name" ?

Comment: Are you look for the create statements?

Comment: yes, I am looking for the "Create table" statement.

Comment: Any help is much appreciated or direction.

Answer (score 0):

Ther are several problems :

- The key on `date_send` is defined `using hash` while you are using it in `order by date_sent`.
- You have a where clause with `brand.status` and `brand.archive`. `archive` is only in a combined key `brand_id, status, archive`, but it cannot be used because the first column (brand_id) is not used in the where clause. Create an index for `archive` only, or a composite `(status, archive)`.
- `subject` needs an index on its own. Currently its index is buried deep down in a composite index.

As a general rule the order of the columns in a composite indexes important. The index is only useful if the used columns are the first ones. Also they are less effective the wider the first column is. This means that

```
KEY `snap_indx` (`snapshot_id`,`snapshot_guid`,`email`(255),`date_sent`,`subject`(255),`status`,`archive`)
```

is inefficient because `subject` with its 255 bytes comes before `status` and `archive` which have only 4 bytes each.

Comment: Hi Lorenz, made some changes based on your feedback but still having issues.

please see my edit above.

Comment: Any ideas on what index I should be adding? At this time the query is still taking the 4 - 5seconds.

Comment: Clean up your indexes, keep those you need. Then, using explain try to create the optimum indexes. Avoid `Using temporary` and `Using filesort`.